# Is there a way to map the Cu3 gate to represent a unitary matrix whose elements are complex in nature

Tags: qiskit, quantum-gate, matlab

I have this 2*2 unitary matrix one looks like
U =[ -0.2840 - 0.5319i,  -0.0000 - 0.7978i; -0.0000 - 0.7978i  ,-0.2840 + 0.5319i]
I want to represent this unitary matrix by a CU3 gate which looks like

[image]

Can someone suggest a faster way to determine all the angles?  Is there any open-source code that I can use to determine these angles?
Thank you for any help and suggestions.

Comment: Just a brief side note: The matrix you've put up seems to be the one for IBM's U3 gate, not the controlled-U3 (=CU3). The controlled version would be represented by a 4x4 matrix, since it acts on two qubits.

Answer (score 2):

You can essentially just read off those angles. Consider the top-left matrix element
$$
U_{00}=-0.2840-0.5319i=e^{i\gamma}\cos(\theta/2).
$$
If you take the mod-square, you get
$$
|U_{00}|^2=0.2840^2+0.5319^2=\cos^2(\theta/2).
$$
From there,
$$
e^{i\gamma}=U_{00}/\cos(\theta/2).
$$
Alternatively,
$$
\tan\gamma=\frac{-0.5319}{-0.2840}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

You can use Qiskit's [`OneQubitEulerDecomposer`](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.OneQubitEulerDecomposer.html) class as follows:

```
from qiskit.quantum_info.synthesis.one_qubit_decompose import OneQubitEulerDecomposer
import numpy as np

unitary = np.array([
    [-0.284 - 0.5319j, -0.0 - 0.7978j],
    [ -0.0 - 0.7978j ,-0.284 + 0.5319j]
])

decomposer = OneQubitEulerDecomposer('U3')
theta, phi, lambda_, gamma = decomposer.angles_and_phase(unitary)
```